# How to use regex to find in between words and spaces?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, katex

I'm so frustrated and lost. I would really appreciate your help here.
I'm trying to fix an issue in Katex and Guppy keyboard. I'm trying to generate a regex to find between the word `matrix` and find the `slash` that has spaces before and after and replace it with a double slash. The problem I have here is it keeps selecting all slashes between matrix

```js
 \left(\begin{matrix}    \sqrt[ 5  ]{ 6  \phantom{\tiny{!}}}     \   \dfrac{ 55  }{ 66  }       \end{matrix}\right)
```

I want to ignore `\sqrt` because the slash doesn't have a couple of spaces on both sides

to something like this

```js
\left(\begin{matrix}    \sqrt[ 5  ]{ 6  \phantom{\tiny{!}}}     \\   \dfrac{ 55  }{ 66  }       \end{matrix}\right)
```

Here is my current half working code

```js
const regex = /matrix(.*?)\\(.*?)matrix/g;
equation = equation.replace(regex, 'matrix$1\\\\$2matrix');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match using this regex:

```bash
({matrix}.*? \\)( .*?(?={matrix}))
```

And replace with: `$1\\$2`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xEYlUO/2)

**Code:**

```js
var equation = String.raw` \left(\begin{matrix}    \sqrt[ 5  ]{ 6  \phantom{\tiny{!}}}     \   \dfrac{ 55  }{ 66  }       \end{matrix}\right)`;
const re = /({matrix}.*? \\)( .*?(?={matrix}))/g;

equation = equation.replace(re, '$1\\$2'); 

console.log(equation);
```

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `({matrix}.*? \\)`: Capture group #1 to match from `{matrix}` to  `\`
- `( .*?{matrix})`: Capture group #1 to match from a single space to `{matrix}`
- In replacement we insert a `\` between 2 back-references

Comment: Also, sorry if it's another topic, but do you recommend any article where I can learn more about Guppy Keyboard and KaTeX? It's either hard to find or I'm not googling things right.

Comment: What I mean here,  will this match the very first begin matrix and the very last end matrix instead of matching each pair of begin/end?

Comment: Hey @anubhava, this works perfectly but it only replaces the first occurrence of matrix so when I have something more complex like this, it only matches the first group of matrix
`\dfrac{  \left(   \sqrt{  \left(\begin{matrix}   5   \\   \left(\begin{matrix}   66   \  11     \end{matrix}\right)       \end{matrix}\right)    \phantom{\tiny{!}}}    ,  \sqrt[ 6  ]{ 66  \phantom{\tiny{!}}}     \right)    }{ 6  }  5 \dfrac{ 22  }{ 5  }`

Comment: Check my updated answer and see new demo. It should work for multiple matches of `" / "` between closest `{matrix}` pairs.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked beautifully! I was thinking to create a function that loops through all of them and then applies a simpler regex but your answer does the same thing too. Not so sure in terms of performance.